# Prove the set of polynomials of degree n forms a basis for a vectorspace

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces, solution-verification

> Let polynomials $p_0(x), p_1(x), p_2(x), ..., p_n(x)$ of $F_n[x]$ have
> degrees $0, 1, 2, ..., n,$ respectively. Prove that this set of
> polynomials is a basis for $F_n[x]$.

With $F_n[x]$ being the ring of polynomials of degree $≤n$ over some field $F$, and $p_k(x)$  are elements of $F_n[x]$ i.e. polynomials of given degrees $k≤n$.

Is the following a valid proof?

We will denote the set of polynomials $p_0(x), p_1(x), p_2(x), ..., p_n(x) =  S$

(1) Proof $S$ spans $F_n[x]$:

Any polynomial in $p \in F_n[x]$ with $p = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + a_0(1)$ can be represented by a linear combination of $S$, $b_nx^n + b_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + b_0(1)$, where $b_n = a_n$. Thus $S$ spans $F_n[x]$.

(2) Proof that $S$ is linearly independent:

Suppose $b_nx^n + b_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ... + b_0(1) = 0 = 0x^n + 0x^{n-1} + ... + 0(1)$. By equating coefficients, we can clearly see $b_n = b_{n-1} = ... = 0$. Thus $S$ is linearly independent.

Following from (1) and (2), $S$ forms a basis on $F_n[x]$.

Comment: You seem to assume that $p_k(x)=x^k$, but that's not necessarily so. All you know is that $\text{deg } p_k = k$.

Comment: Also, your proof of linear independence depends on the functions $x \mapsto x^k$ being linearly independent. You need to establish this fact independently, so to speak.

Comment: @dxiv What is the difference between $F_n[x]$ and $p_n(x)$?

Comment: @Joeyboy It's your question, so I guess you are supposed to know what $F_n[x]$ is - and should, in fact, [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4346253/edit) the question to clarify it. From the context, $F_n[x]$ could be the ring of polynomials of degree $\le n$ over some field $F$. On the other hand, $p_k(x)$ are elements of $F_n[x]$ i.e. polynomials of given degrees $k \le n$.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you. I had not seen this notation previously in the source text, and assumed it was standard notation of some sort.

Comment: Your subject line does not match the problem you are considering.